# Empty variable in header fpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf

I tried to show an variable in header like an Invoice but doesn't work, I using FPDF but the field `$ordenTrabajo` is empty, I tried this:

```
<?php


    $ordenTrabajo=$_POST['oT_Escondido'];

    ob_end_clean(); //    the buffer and never prints or returns anything.
    ob_start(); // it starts buffering
    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
    // Cabecera de página



    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        //$this->Image('../dist/img/logo.jpg',10,8,33);
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
        // Movernos a la derecha
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Título
        $this->Cell(120,10,'Control de Empaques IKOR PUNTARENAS SA',0,1,'C');

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        // Salto de línea
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->Cell(40,10,'Orden de Trabajo: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, "GORE-5265", 0, 0);
        $this->Cell(13,10,'OC#: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, "OC-123456789", 0, 0);
        $this->Cell(30,10,'Peso: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, "19,45 KG", 0,0 );
        $this->Cell(50,10,'Cantidad de Cajas: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, "1000", 0, 1);

        $this->Cell(20,10,'Lote: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(40, 10,'123456789', 0, 0);
        $this->Cell(50,10,'Numero de Parte: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, "PARTE-999999", 0, 0);
        $this->Cell(40,10,'Filtros por caja: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(20, 10, "11", 0,0 );
        $this->Cell(50,10,'Cantidad de Filtros: ',0,0);
        $this->Cell(30, 10, "9999", 0, 1);
        $this->Ln(15);
        $this->Line(80, 45, 100, 45); // 20mm from each edge
        $this->Line(50, 45, 210-50, 45); // 50mm from each edge

    }

    public function setLote($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    // Pie de página
    function Footer()
    {
        // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Número de página
        //$this->Cell(300,10,'7FMIKO-022 REV.02',0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(-15,10,'7FMIKO-022 REV.02',0,0,'C');
    }
    }

    // Creación del objeto de la clase heredada
    $pdf = new PDF('L');
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(30,10,$ordenTrabajo,0,1);
    $pdf->Output();
    ob_end_flush(); // It's printed here, because ob_end_flush "prints" what's in
                  // the buffer, rather than returning it
                  //     (unlike the ob_get_* functions)
    ?>
```

How could I fix it? Thanx

**EDIT**

I can't show the value in the header even with the global variable

```
$ordenTrabajo=$_POST['oT_Escondido'];

ob_end_clean(); //    the buffer and never prints or returns anything.
ob_start(); // it starts buffering
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Cabecera de página



function Header()
{
    global $ordenTrabajo;
    // Logo
    //$this->Image('../dist/img/logo.jpg',10,8,33);
    // Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Movernos a la derecha
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Título
    $this->Cell(120,10,'Control de Empaques IKOR PUNTARENAS SA',0,1,'C');

    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    // Salto de línea
    $this->Ln(10);
    $this->Cell(40,10,'Orden de Trabajo: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(40, 10, "GORE-5265", 0, 0);
    $this->Cell(13,10,'OC#: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(40, 10, "OC-123456789", 0, 0);
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Peso: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(40, 10, "19,45 KG", 0,0 );
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Cantidad de Cajas: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(30, 10, "1000", 0, 1);

    $this->Cell(20,10,'Lote: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(40, 10,$ordenTrabajo, 0, 0);
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Numero de Parte: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(40, 10, "PARTE-999999", 0, 0);
    $this->Cell(40,10,'Filtros por caja: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(20, 10, "11", 0,0 );
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Cantidad de Filtros: ',0,0);
    $this->Cell(30, 10, "9999", 0, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is used to render the page header. It is automatically called by AddPage() and should not be called directly by the application.The implementation in FPDF is empty, so you have to subclass it and override the method if you want a specific processing.

Source: http://www.fpdf.org/